# How to configure mapping of JSON fields to TypeScript object properties?

Tags: javascript, json, mapping, typescript-typings

Input JSON:

```
{
  "some_field":"some value"
}
```

Type to be used for mapping:

```typescript
export inteface SomeType {
  someField:string;
}
```

How can the mapping between JSON and TypeScript type be configured so that some_field -> someField?

Answer (score 2):

You could use decorators to do that . see this post for more details [Type Script Decorators](http://cloudmark.github.io/Json-Mapping/)

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem entirely, but it's a good starting point.